# Web-Push API: Is it possible to use in a native app

Tags: android, web-push

We are going to be making a very simple native wrapper application for a client, which wraps a website, and are going to be required to add push notification support. I was just curious if it is possible to beat two birds with one stone and add support for both desktop and **android** push using only the web-push API.

Seeing as chrome supports web push, and the native web view uses the chrome engine, I can imagine how this is possible. But I can also see the flip side of how it would be hard to make this interact with the android push notification permissions system.

Side question: I am aware of services like https://pushover.net, but a requirement is that all notifications are end-to-end encrypted. Do any services like pushovere support this?

Comment: No, you cannot use the Push API inside a native/hybrid app.

Comment: BTW what is the advantage of building an app that "wraps a website"? The only reason for that used to be push notifications, but now with web push and services like Pushpad I think it doesn't make sense anymore

Comment: @collimarco Thanks for the response! We'll implement it in the app then. The reason the client wants an app is because they want to be on the app store. We make responsive websites, so we can't offer a native app, but we can give them what they want, which is to be searchable on the app store

Answer (score 0):

WebView does not support neither the push or the notification API in any way. For that piece you are going to need to use java bridge and bare GCM + the android notification api.

The actual server side code that sends messages to gcm can be partially reused especially since you apparently need to encrypt end to end on the native app as well (but you will need to deal with the decryption side on android yourself whereas chrome does that for you).

I would move the pushover.net and encryption paragraph to a different question to make things clearer.